# Tourist 90 days visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I came to Berlin on December 27 and stayed until now.  My 90 days are almost over but last week I went to Croatia (which is not part of Schengen) for one night and came back to Berlin. My friends have told me that once I'm out of Schengen area I can restart my 90 days again.

Can I stay in Schengen area for another 90 days after leaving it for one day or do I have to leave it for 3 months to restart the 90 days period?

Comment: If you want to stay longer than allowed by a tourist visa, you should ask at Expatriates Stack Exchange.

Comment: @o.m. but the question was rejected there as off topic. A good question for expatriates is "how can I stay in Germany for the purpose of the course I want to take," but that's not being asked here. This question is about the rules for a tourist visa.

Answer (score 9):

Your friends are wrong.

Unless you have a long-stay visa or residence permit, you can only be in the Schengen area for 90 days out of *any* 180. Leaving and reentering does not change that.

(Another way to state this is that *at any point on time* you must be able to point to 90 different dates within the last 180 days when you were outside Schengen *for that entire day*, midnight to midnight).

Going to Croatia for a single night doesn't even affect the counting, because both the day you exit and the day you enter count as days in Schengen.

Comment: But doesn't the stamp on the passport counts? ?

Comment: @JimenaBanderas: The stamp in the passport is nothing more than documentation of _when_ you traveled into and out of the Schengen area, such that one can count days for the 90-of-180 rule. The stamp is _not a visa_ and does not entitle you to 90 days of stay.

Comment: Thank you henning,  I've got a last question: if I want to stay for a German language course starting on April,  could I extend my visa or start my course while the student VISA is in tramit?  Should I ask in auslanderbehorde? ?

Comment: @JimenaBanderas: The _only_ way to stay legally beyond the 90-day-rule is to get a national long-stay visa or residence permit (or asylum or citizenship, etc). There is no way to extend the 90-day count itself.